# Append to an object selected from a list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a minimal version of my problem, given:

```
<div class="foo">
   <div class="a"> </div>
   <div class="b"> </div>
   <div class="c"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to insert the element `<div class="bar">WORKS!</div>` into one of the children randomly.

```
var kids = $(.foo).children();
var idx  = Math.floor(Math.random() * kids.length);
var target = kids[idx];
```

I think this is a misunderstanding between how javascript and jQuery work together. I'm learning both at the moment, so here is my due diligence in solving the problem:

- `target.append(...)` fails since target is not a JQuery object and `.append()` is a JQuery call.
- `$(target).append(...)` does strange things, copying items around in the DOM and I don't understand why. It may work in this isolated example, but it's causing crazy town with many foo's, a's, b's and c's.
- `target.innerHTML=...` doesn't seem to work and I don't want to erase any previous content with the append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
var target = kids.eq(idx);
```

instead of,

```
var target = kids[idx];
```

Please read **[here](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to know more about `.eq()`

Answer (score 1):

Try [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
var target = kids.eq(idx);
```